# the use of rob with cars

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering why you can say 
"I robbed a bank and stole the money..." or 
"I robbed a post office..." or 
"The bus was robbed while the passengers were at the restaurant"

But it sounds extremely strange to say:

"Last night, my car was robbed and they took my stereo, my money and all of my CDs."

The more common way to express that would be my car was broken into but why can't you say my car was robbed or my purse was robbed"?

Comment: Because when your car was stolen it was ***you*** who were robbed, not your car.

Comment: I am not talking about my car being stolen I am talking about the things inside

Answer (score 8):

The major difference between the verbs *steal* and *rob* -- which can both refer to the same event --
is that the object of *steal* is the thing stolen, but the object of *rob* is the owner of the thing stolen.
Thus

- *He stole $3,000/a Maserati/everything.*
- *He robbed the bank/Harry/everybody.*

but not

- **He robbed $3,000/a Maserati/everything.*
- **He stole the bank/Harry/everybody.*

Comment: You could say "He stole the bank" if he physically removed the building from its location (unlikely, but there have been stranger heists), or if he somehow stole control of the bank corporation (I'm certain this has happened many times).

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the reason that the ideas of "robbing a bank" or a "train robbery" make sense is the implication that the people inside (or the organization itself) are the real victims of the theft. Corporations are often thought of as entities (e.g. Google says...) but I don't think that most people think of cars as living entities in the same way. I think when a container or similar inanimate object is stolen from, it is "burgled" rather than "robbed."

Answer (score 1):

Legally, *[robbery](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1868)* is a particular form of theft

> the direct taking of property (including money) from a person (victim) through force, threat or intimidation.

*law.com*

Breaking into a house at night, with no one home, is not robbery. Nor is the taking of a car (or its contents) when the owner is not around.  Carjacking, on the other hand, **is** robbery.

Surreptitiously pilfering a purse is probably not robbery, but purse snatching, especially violently is.

In lay parlance, we use these terms loosely. (Technically, in many jurisdictions, assault is not hitting, battery is.)

Comment: *Technically, assault is not hitting, battery is.*  It depends on the jurisdiction.  In New York State, physical injury is an element of all crimes of assault. In other jurisdictions, assault is the threat; battery is the physical contact.

Comment: So what about when it is said that "A bank was robbed last night" meaning after hours while no one was there. Or is there a different term for that as well?

Comment: If there is no guard on duty, *robbery* is not the right term (technically, but do we [other than us lawyers] really care)?

Comment: @deadrat Yeah, that's the general common law vs. state law thing. Almost all these terms are jurisdictionally sensitive.

Comment: I was trying to explain to an ESL learner why you can't rob a car but you can rob a bank and I got stuck because they are both locations that can be robbed and if both don't have anyone inside how do you explain why we don't say rob a car but we do say rob a bank.

Comment: @Masha It's not robbery unless there are people in the bank other than the criminals.

Comment: @deadrat so what is it called when people break into a bank and steal the money but noone is there... there is no one word for that? It would be the bank was broken into?

Comment: @Masha Breaking into the bank with the intent to steal is called *burglary*.  *Burglarize* is the verb, and there is a colloquial back-formation *burgle*.  Actually taking something from the bank is *theft* or *larceny*.  *Thieve* is the verb, but its use is intransitive, "to be a thief"; you don't say "I thieved a bank."

Comment: @Masha It's probably a *bank burglary* in most US jurisdictions. The US statute for bank robbery reads "Whoever, by force and violence, or by intimidation, takes, or attempts to take, from the person or presence of another, ... of, any bank, credit union, or any savings and loan association; ...
Shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than twenty years." It requires *persons* to be present.